# How to auto-generate excel reports based on a SharePoint custom list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-addin

I would like to utilize SharePoint 2007 platform to help do auto-reporting. Scenario is as below:

I have a custom list, e.g.

```
Employee    Project    Hours    Month
Mike        A          10       January
Tom         B          5        April
```

I'm thinking of writing some code extension to implement this:

- Whenever there's an update to the custom list (add/delete/modify), There will be a set of excel report files created/updated in a particular SharePoint document library.
- The excel report files include summary reports for each month, and a report for YTD (year-to-date).

Is it a feasible design and how should I do the code customization? currently I have no idea what kind of technology/framework/code samples I shall research

Comment: Do you really mean 2007? Isn't that already totally out of support.

Comment: @JamesZ unfortunately yes Our organization provides SharePoint 2007 only.